# Why can't I use value = = setjmp(env);

Tags: c, setjmp, clib

Recently while reading csapp, I find in nonlocal jump, I can't use

```
int value;
value = setjmp(env);
```

but I can use this

```
if(setjmp(env)){
   // code
}
```

Why?

```
int value;
value = setjmp(env);
```